# Python argparse AssertionError using multiple groups

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am playing around with 'argparse' and I can't get two specific groups (sg and dg) to work at the same time.

```
import argparse
import os


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Output contents of Spreadsheet into Data Structures or Render jinja2 template"
)

parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', help='Output to terminal only (Default)')

ss_args = parser.add_argument_group('Spreadsheet Options', 'Modify options for opening spreadsheet')
ss_args.add_argument('-f', '--input_file', type=str, metavar='', required=True,
                     help="Spreadsheet Input File (e.g. 'configs.xlsx') - (Required)")

ss_args.add_argument('-i', '--index', type=str, metavar='', help="Index of Datasets from Spreadsheet")

ss_args.add_argument('-sh', '--sheet', type=str, metavar='', help="Specify Sheet in Excel File to use")

ss_args.add_argument('-T', '--transposed', action='store_true',
                     help="Spreadsheet is Transposed (i.e. Column per device)")

sg = parser.add_argument_group('Saving Options', 'Output Saving Options (JSON/YAML Only)')
save_group = sg.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
save_group.add_argument('-S', '--save', action='store_true',
                        help='Save JSON/YAML configurations per device to file')
save_group.add_argument('-s', '--savecompiled', action='store_true',
                        help='Save JSON/YAML configurations per device to file')

dg = parser.add_argument_group('Data Structures', 'Output Data Structure Options')
data_group = dg.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
data_group.add_argument('-j', '--json', action='store_true', help="Output as JSON (Default)")
data_group.add_argument('-y', '--yaml', action='store_true', help="Output as YAML")
data_group.add_argument('-t', '--template', type=str, metavar='', help="Specify jinja2 template")

arguments = parser.parse_args()
```

When I run the code, I get an assertionerror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spreadsheet_to_data.py", line 56, in <module>
    arguments = parser.parse_args()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 1730, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 1762, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 1968, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 1908, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 1836, in take_action
    action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 1020, in __call__
    parser.print_help()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 2362, in print_help
    self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 2346, in format_help
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 282, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 213, in format_help
    item_help = join([func(*args) for func, args in self.items])
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 213, in <listcomp>
    item_help = join([func(*args) for func, args in self.items])
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\argparse.py", line 333, in _format_usage
    assert ' '.join(opt_parts) == opt_usage
AssertionError
```

If I comment out one of the groups 'sg' or 'dg, it works fine.

```
usage: spreadsheet_to_data.py [-h] [-v] -f  [-i] [-sh] [-T] [-j | -y | -t ]

Output contents of Spreadsheet into Data Structures or Render jinja2 template

optional arguments:
  -h, --help          show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose       Output to terminal only (Default)

Spreadsheet Options:
  Modify options for opening spreadsheet

  -f , --input_file   Spreadsheet Input File (e.g. 'configs.xlsx') -
                      (Required)
  -i , --index        Index of Datasets from Spreadsheet
  -sh , --sheet       Specify Sheet in Excel File to use
  -T, --transposed    Spreadsheet is Transposed (i.e. Column per device)

Data Structures:
  Output Data Structure Options

  -j, --json          Output as JSON (Default)
  -y, --yaml          Output as YAML
  -t , --template     Specify jinja2 template
```

I just can't seem to get both to work at the same time - any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "run it", how are you invoking the program from the command-line?  If I copy-paste this code, add `print(arguments)` to the bottom, and run it either with `--help` or with `-f blah`, I get no error in Python 3.7 (Windows or macOS).

Comment: Actually the code you provided works fine in Python 3.6 https://trinket.io/python3/d41f438371?showInstructions=true

Comment: What is your exact python version?

Comment: There was a bugfix to Python 3.6 argparse: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/7528 merged in June 2018 - if your python is older - it's most likely the cause.

Comment: Cheers, all. I was in Python 3.6.2 and looks like was this bug. Have tried in other versions and ok. Cheers all.